# Ruby-on-Rails 3.2: Export a CSV with a large data set (100,000 records)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, scalability, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Introduction**

I have a app that has multiple tables, some with and some without associations.

Some tables will be required to hold around 100,000 entries.

The app is using Rails 3.2 on Ruby 1.9 and hosted on Heroku. I have access to workers if needed.

**The Requirement in Question**

A vital requirement for the app is to allow users to export the data as a CSV - a requirement for this is to allow the user to filter what data they want to export but I am not worrying about that at the moment as you will see from the data below, I have hard-coded what data is to be exported but this does rule out creating a rake task to just export the whole table.

Also the method implemented must be factored to allow to be used by multiple tables to avoid unnessaccery code repeating.

**Current Solution**

I am implementing delayed_job in my app and performing a CSV generate in a job. While doing this I am following the solution found here at http://www.ayokasystems.com/blog/delegating-long-running-jobs-in-rails/ from 'abdullah'.

The idea being is to generate the data in CSV format and save it in a LONGTEXT field in the UserJobs table to allow the user to download once complete and at a future time.

**The Problem**

The method used from the above tutorial works fine in my app until I run a job of 100,000 records at once. To overcome this I have tried to add the cool find_each function to the perform method but delayed job worker reports back a error everytime it tries to process it:

```
[Worker(host:*** pid:18637)] ReportJob failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Title:0x007ff20c1ec1b0> - 0 failed attempts
[Worker(host:*** pid:18637)] ReportJob failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Title:0x007ff20ec47f18> - 1 failed attempts
[Worker(host:*** pid:18637)] 2 jobs processed at 10.5219 j/s, 2 failed ...
```

My code for the perform method is:

```
def perform
  Title.find_each do |titles|
    csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
      titles.each do |t|
        csv << t.to_csv
      end
    end
    user_job = UserJob.find(user_job_id)
    user_job.update_attribute :data, csv_data
  end
end
```

Can anyone see what the issue could be, I am thinking I have just made a stupid mistake with how I am looping through things.

I am very open to any other suggestions to how to accomplish the requirement in question but please bear in mind the limitations I have with Heroku.

Comment: Have made a edit to my code as I just saw I forgot to assign the CSV.generate to csv_data to use to update the record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to iterate with *each* but titles in this case are instances of title (not array).

```
csv_vals = []
columns = [:name, :release_date, :studio]

Title.find_each(:select => columns) do |title| 
  columns.each {|value| csv_vals << "#{title[value]}"}
end

# comma separated string 
csv_string = csv_vals.join(',')
```

There is more elegant way to formulate CSV string but I am too lazy to experiment.

What is important is that you are doing SELECT only on columns you need. For 100 000 records that adds to a lot of less bandwidth DB communication. With just *find_each* you get all columns for each row and you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however another requirement is that this method will accept data from other tables in the future so I wouldn't want to implement a select. 
I know in the question I listed specific fields that would lead to the assumption you made but this was just for reference, I have amended the question to fix this.
But good answer and will remember this technique for the future.

Comment: You can take columns param as method param, the code will work with different columns. In any case remember if you are going to find_each and there a lot of records, use select :)

Comment: Sorry, I would but I don't have enough rep to do this yet. Will do as soon as I can!

Comment: I have tried the code but now I get a different error in the worker of ReportJob failed with 'ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away' which breaks the worker, this happens when it is making the UPDATE to the DB, in the following code line which I have placed below your code block - user_job.update_attribute :data, csv_string

Comment: You are using delayed_jobs table and trying to write to column data (there is no data column there) unless you added it manually by default there is no that column.

Comment: For your purposes you may create new table where you are going to save your CSV data. Also use method ActiveRecord.update_attributes!({:column_name => value})

Comment: It is writing to a different table called UserJob where there is a longtext field called data. Should also mentioned I have a line of code above your block which finds the UserJob record to update.
`user_job = UserJob.find(user_job_id)`

Answer (score 1):

`find_each` yields a single record to the block, not a collection, hence your error calling `each` on a single record. Take a look at [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches), OR fix your code to use the single record:

```
Title.find_each do |title|
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << title.to_csv
  end
  user_job = UserJob.find(user_job_id)
  user_job.update_attribute :data, csv_data
end
```

Comment: BTW this is just to fix your particular error - I'm not offering an opinion on the efficiency of that code.

Comment: Thanks for picking this up and referencing to the api!